# accessing keys of typescript interface with variables

Tags: typescript, interface

In typescript I have an interface as follows:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  hobby: string;
  address?: string;
  email?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;
}
```

I have another function as follows where I try to check if there are any missing fields from the above interface:

```
export const getMissingFields = async (person: Person): Promise<string[]> => {
  const potentialMissingFields = ['address', 'email', 'phoneNumber']
  const missingFields = [];
  for (const field of potentialMissingFields) {
    if (!person[field]) {
      missingFields.push(field)
    }
  }
  return missingFields;
};
```

However, I get an error with `!person[field]` saying `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Person'.  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Person'.`

Does anyone know how I'd be able to properly access the keys/values of the interface so I can check if the `person` variables has missing fields? I know I can write if statements to manually check each key but ideally I'd like to be able to check for more missing fields later just by adding another value in the `potentialMissingFields` list rather than writing a new if statement each time.

Comment: Make potentialMissingFields as const

Comment: it's already a const?

Comment: No the `as const` to make it a tuple

Comment: ok this seems to work - thanks